# Python's recvfrom() function not returning any data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, upnp, ssdp

I would like to preface that I am new to networking and still working on my python skills so go easy on me.

I have started working on a network scanning project and have played with multiple protocols to try and find what works best for my purposes. SSDP seems to be the best for me thus I have been playing with a little universal plug and play script I found to try and test how things are working on my network.

```py
import socket  
import sys

dst = "239.255.255.250"  
st = "upnp:rootdevice"  
msg = [  
    'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1',
    'Host:239.255.255.250:1900',
    'Man:"ssdp:discover"',
    'MX:1',
    'ST:%s' % (st,),
    '']
    
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 0))
print(s.getsockname())
s.settimeout(60)
byte_data = '\r\n'.join(msg) 
s.sendto(bytes(byte_data, 'utf-8'), (dst, 1900))
while True:  
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(32*1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("timeout has occurred")
        break
    print (f"$ {addr}\n{data}")
s.close()
```

For some reason this always times out for me and never displays any data. After investigating using WireShark, I can see that my computer is sending out searches and devices are sending replies back to my computer. Does anyone know why this might be occurring (OS is windows 10). I will say I have increased the timeout numerous times to high amounts and still nothing is getting through.

Comment: I believe you have to call `.bind()` on the socket, so that `.recvfrom()` knows what port to listen on.

Comment: @jasonharper yea I noticed that after making this post but it is still not working after binding it to a port. I looked a little closer into the wireshark stuff and it seems that actually no devices are responding to me (but are responding to other ssdp searches) which gives me the impression that my packet may be malformed. (added edited code in)

Comment: One difference I noted in another Python SSDP implementation is that they had two blank strings at the end of their equivalent of `msg`, so that the message ends with `\r\n\r\n` - perhaps that's relevant.

Comment: jason is correct: you are missing the extra "\r\n" in the end (the M-SEARCH message pretends to be a HTTP header section and the empty line is the end-of-headers marker)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, there should be an extra blank line in the M-SEARCH request header, so.

```
import socket
import sys

dst = "239.255.255.250"
st = "upnp:rootdevice"
msg = [
    'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1',
    'Host:239.255.255.250:1900',
    'Man:"ssdp:discover"',
    'MX:1',
    'ST:%s' % (st,),
    '',
    '']

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 0))
print(s.getsockname())
s.settimeout(2)
byte_data = '\r\n'.join(msg)
s.sendto(bytes(byte_data, 'utf-8'), (dst, 1900))
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(32 * 1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        print("timeout has occurred")
        break
    print(f"$ {addr}\n{data}")
s.close()
```

Now it works. Also, with the SSDP MX header set to 1 it is pointless setting timeout to 60 - any device responding to the request MUST reply within MX seconds or not at all.

As it is, this should work fine on a system with a single network interface. But on a multi-homed system you will need to send the request on each interface by binding a socket to that interface, otherwise some UPNP devices might not be reachable.